# Golang Cloud SDK - gcloud app deploy cannot find import package

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

according to the official documentation for Google App Engine Standard environment (Go API) the "[preferred tooling to deploy a project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/download)" is now the *Cloud SDK* and so we moved to gcloud from goapp.

We are unable to deploy Go projects to GAE because all the sub-packages of every given project can't be found at "deploy time".
The typical folder structure that we have been using for every GAE project was as follows:

```
-project-name
--app.yaml
--main.go
--assets
---package1
---package2
```

When global libraries were put in the system GOPATH everything worked smoothly.

Running `gcloud app deploy` we now get this:

```
You are about to deploy the following services:
 - yourproject/default/123456789 (from [/Path/to/app.yaml])
     Deploying to URL: [https://yourproject.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Staging command [/path/to/yourproject/app.yaml /var/folders/b6/5ydn0wdn64jd32sxzzz48b7c0000gn/T/tmpbd4oiG] failed with return code [1].

------------------------------------ STDOUT ------------------------------------
------------------------------------ STDERR ------------------------------------
2017/03/24 10:25:58 failed analyzing /path/to/yourproject: cannot find package "yourpackage" in any of:
        ($GOROOT not set)
        /path/to/gopath/src/yourpackage (from $GOPATH)
GOPATH: /path/to/gopath
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

while `dev_appserver.py` works perfectly keeping the same folder structure.

Did we miss something? 
How can we deploy to Google App Engine Standard environment using gcloud?

If the project structure needs to be changed: how? Is there official documentation about it?

Thanks in advance,

**Edit --** Further infos:

```
Luigi-Mac-Pro:path/to/yourproject distudio$ gcloud version
Google Cloud SDK 148.0.0
app-engine-go 
app-engine-go-darwin-x86_64 1.9.50
app-engine-python 1.9.50
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.24
core 2017.03.17
core-nix 2016.11.07
gcloud 
gcloud-deps 2017.03.17
gcloud-deps-darwin-x86_64 2017.02.21
gsutil 4.23
gsutil-nix 4.22
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google recommends keeping your dependencies outside of the app directory, and using `GOPATH` to refer them. In your case, that would mean doing the following:

```
-project-name
--app.yaml
--main.go
```

where `main.go` contains

```
import (
    "package1"
    "package2"
)
```

And somewhere else:

```
-my_packages
--src
---package1
---package2
```

And then set `GOPATH` environment variable to `path/to/my_packages` prior to running `dev_appserver` and `gcloud app deploy`.

### For the future

We are working out the long term solution for properly vendoring packages inside your app directory – likely using Go's future native package manager. I'm sorry to say that we don't have a good way of supporting sub-packages for `gcloud app deploy`. This was an unfortunate side effect of compatibility with the App Engine Flexible environment.

Comment: is there an official documentation for this?

Comment: @Betamos even Google's own package like golang.org/x/net/context couldn't work with gcloud...... what's the point? I'm talking about App Engine Standard environment. Documentations is surely missing a very basic tutorial on this and both new and old users got stuck using gcloud sdk

Comment: @LawrenceMok Could you please create a separate question, or alternatively file a bug to https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches ? It sounds like a bug, but it's hard to say without more information. Also note that go1.8 support is coming to the Cloud SDK in release 162.

Comment: In a general way, this issue looks like [one that I hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228766/errors-with-a-golang-web-app-hosted-in-a-google-app-engine-environment-the-app) a few days ago because of problems with package imports. My case involved package dependencies that Google hosts. Specifically, the BigQuery and Iterator packages.